# Extending wifi range with an external antenna

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, antenna

I've got an old antenna that I'd like to try and use to get a bit more wifi range/signal strength out of my laptop.  The antenna is terminated with a male TS9 connector, such as the one pictured here:

[image: TS9 male connector; yes, there's a pin in there]

...and of course the wireless card I want to connect it to uses the standard male UFL type connector.

So it seems like this should be a case of simply tracking down a cable that has a female TS9 connector on one end, and a female UFL connector on the other.  However, the only TS9 adaptors that I can find all seem to be terminated with a male connector.

Is there a reason for this?  Or perhaps some other term that is used to refer to a female TS9 connector?  What do I need to track down in order to connect the antenna to my laptop's wireless card?

For reference, a 'female TS9 connector' looks like this:

[image: I need a cable with one of these on one end]

Comment: Just beware, the wrong antennae can damage the transmitter - been there, done that.  I have no further answer, just a warning. :)

Comment: The alternative to extend your range: get another router which supports dd-wrt and setup a wireless repeater (for example as explained here: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) or buy a commercially off the shelf wifi repeater (ridiculous expensive imho).

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It will give you nothing. Only an other antenna will not give you a better range at all. You need more power or amplifier to do that. A little thing you can do is just to install your router or what ever a little bit higher (1,5 meter over the floor) so the Fresnel zone do not disturb by the floor. So forget it.